# Clock and Fonts scaling up in pad pro

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am working on a application, in which first I run the app with Ipad Air and then with Ipad pro simulator with same scale then, the fonts and clock scale up in ipad pro. I am unable to understand why this thing is happening in ipad pro.I have searched for this issue but there nothing helpful related to this.So I need help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you include a proper Launch Screen file in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Your app probably gets scaled because you do not have a launch storyboard.

1. Add a launch story board via New->File->User Interface->Launch Screen
2. Make sure you select it in your projects setting under 'Launch Screen File'

Comment: In our project ,we are not using the launch storyboard.We are using image.xcassets. I am pretty new to the Development. So i need some help in this regard.

Comment: Hi, if you are not using a launch storyboard it is not possible to support native iPad Pro resolution, this is intended by Apple. You might have noticed that you cannot provide a Launch-Image for iPad Pro in the image.xcassets. The launch storyboard tells the app that it should use native iPad Pro resolution, otherwise your app gets scaled up. Hope this helps

Comment: Even if i add a launch storyboard.will it work for all the devices like ipad, iphone and ipad pro?because i have sperate launch images for different images.